# Not able to use customized Ajax HTML editor from code behind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am customizing the ajax html editor. I am creating a class which derives from ajax html editor, and overriding FillTopToolbar() method to have limited toolbar buttons. I am trying to use this in my aspx page.

```
<%@ Register namespace="Content" tagprefix="edit" %>
<edit:MyEditor runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px"/>
```

I am able to see the editor in my aspx page.
The problem comes when I give an ID to the control

```
<edit:MyEditor ID="htmlEditor" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px"/>
```

I get an error in the designer file in the below line.

```
protected global::Content.MYHTMLEditor htmlEditor;
```

I am not able to use it in code behind. I am using VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but try putting this at the top of your code-behind file:

```
using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor;
```

Doing this I was able to create an editor programatticaly and access its members:

```
Editor tempEditor = new Editor();
```